# Java Program to compute nCr throwing Arithmetic Exception "Divide by zero"

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

Following code tries to compute the nCr values for the various values of given n and here r varies from 0 to n.

The input is in the following format :-

Input Format

The first line contains the number of test cases T. 
T lines follow each containing an integer n.

Constraints

```
 1<=T<=200 
 1<=n< 1000
```

Output Format

For each n output the list of nC0 to nCn each separated by a single space in a new line. If the number is large, print only the last 9 digits. i.e. modulo 10^9

So Sample Input is of the follwing format :-

```
 3
 2
 4
 5
```

And the sample output is of the follwing format :-

```
 1 2 1
 1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Here is the code

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.math.*;

public class Solution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        j = 0;
        while(j <= a){
              if( j == 0 || j == a){
                  System.out.print(1 + " ");
              }
              else if( j == 1 || j == (a - 1)){
                  System.out.print(a + " ");
              }else{
                  BigInteger  a1 = (Num(a,j));
                  BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.valueOf(fact(j));
                  BigInteger c1 = a1.divide(b1);
                  BigInteger x1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000000);
                  System.out.print( c1.mod(x1)  +" ");
              } 
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}

public static BigInteger Num(int a, int j){
    BigInteger prod = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){
        int z = a - k;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(z);
        prod = prod.multiply(b);
    }
    return prod;
}

public static long fact(long j){
    long prod = 1;
    for(long i = j; i > 0; i--){
       prod *= i; 
    }
    return prod;
 }
}
```

Its clearing some test cases but its failing in many of them.
Saying Run Time Error, when I tested it on my input of 1 999 it threw Arithmetic Exception "Divide by zero".

Here is the exception log :-

```
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger divide by zero
        at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(MutableBigInteger.java:1179)
        at java.math.BigInteger.divideKnuth(BigInteger.java:2049)
        at java.math.BigInteger.divide(BigInteger.java:2030)
        at Solution.main(Solution.java:25)
```

What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked why `b1` comes out as 0?

Comment: When I am computing factorial I am taking loop index to be greater than zero. So I am not sure what is causing that, exactly that's my problem is?

Comment: This can't be reproduced, and the description is too vague to guess which input might cause the division by zero.

Comment: I tried it for Sample input 1 999 and it gave me that Exception log

Comment: @JohnDoe You should have put this into the Q  :-{

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use BigInteger for the computation of factorials up to around 1000.

```
public static BigInteger fact(long j){
  BigInteger prod = BigInteger.ONE;
  for(long i = j; i > 0; i--){
    BigInteger f = BigInteger.valueOf( i );
    prod = prod.multiply( f ); 
  }
  return prod;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it worked for the test input 999. Please shed some light how you came to the above conclusion.

Comment: Also can you suggest how to improve the run time of the problem ? Should I now resort to Dynamic Prgramming.

Comment: Light: Consider that Long.MAX_VALUE is 9223372036854775807, 19 digits. Multiplying 20 different numbers >= 10 will easily exceed this (so the result will be wrong anyway), and there are enough powers of two in 2..100 to shift everything off the MSB in a long (so the result will be 0).

Comment: Speed: Multiply and divide using integers represented by their prime factors.